# c# byte AND operator

Tags: c#, php, .net

how can I use & operator betwen BYTE and INT?

it is said here:

http://int64.org/docs/gamestat-protocols/ase.html

however in php its working but in c# not...

PHP:

```
if ($flag & 1)
    ...
}
```

c#

```
if (flag & 1)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: You have to be more precisely about "not working". However I am sure `flag & 1 == 1` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

The `flag & 1` part is working - but `if` requires a *Boolean* expression. So you can do:

```
if ((flag & 1) != 0)
```

Note that you have to put parentheses round the `&` expression as `!=` has higher precedence (binds tighter) than `&`.

If you're working with a set of flags though, it's *usually* a better idea to use an enum. For example, look at [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) - you might use:

```
if ((flags & BindingFlags.Instance) != 0)
```

That increases type safety (so you know you're trying to compare it with the right kind of flag) and reduces the use of magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if ((flag & 1) == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

The `&` operator returns an integer in C# whereas `if` expects a boolean expression.